# Passing Future object between activities

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Coming from Java EE to an Android application (i'm not Guru in Java EE), For a fatest load of the application, we decided to process a files asynchronously, when the application starts, we launch some asynchronous channels to read the files, then we open the main activity, the idea is the user may not go directly to the use cases which need these files, but if he go it direclty and the asynchronous read wasn't terminated, he should wait a while(what the client wanted).

My question is how to passe the Future object between activities? my team agreed for using static methods or singletons, but i really don't love singleton because its an antipattern and i don't like static methods because they behave nearly like singleton.

Trying to use parceable or serializable, but future doesn't use implement anyone of it, i tried to use RoboGuice (its based on static fields but its busniss) but its a little buggy, how can i do it in android in pretty way, if there's another idea, i will be obliged to use singleton or static methods.

Comment: What kind of files and data are you talking about?

Comment: Exactly. EventBus can be used to send objects from 1 place to another (e.g. asyncTask to Activity or whatever ).

Comment: We are working on the V2 of the application from the V1 (i didn't worked in V1), the V1 use files to store data, so i don't want to change the whole application and use a database (no time for that) and the client wants a more fast start.

Comment: @Vucko thank you for your time and suggest, i didn't know EventBus until now, i saw its "How to get started" section and it seems pretty solution.

Comment: No problem at all bro. The EventBus library is everything I could've ever asked for. It's elegant, easy to use and does the job. You can send your own custom objects with it from and to virtually anything. I'll migrate my comment to an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) can be used to send objects from 1 place to another (e.g. asyncTask to Activity). It's great and easy to use, and it will accomplish what you're trying to do perfectly.

You can create your custom object classes to send between almost any 2 classes, Activities, Services, or whatever you with.

Comment: This seems a very great solution for sharing datas between components (Intent extras sucks), for instant i will use it only for Future, i won't refactor old code, this makes the application ugly, but i don't think there's other solution with the time provided.

Comment: Yes, intents are very limited to simple data types. This is the greatest way because of 1 more thing: It's completely asynchronous, it's up to you to decide when you'll post an event (for example, in `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask` when you fetch some data).